# A general circle through the intersection points of line $L$ and circle $S_1$ has the form $S_1+\lambda L$. What is the significance of $\lambda$?

Tags: circles

We write a general line $L$ passing through intersection of two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ as $L= L_1 + (\lambda) L_2$ where $\lambda$ is a variable.

Even in family of circles we write a general circle $S$ passing through points of intersection of a circle $S_1$ and a line $L$ as $S= S_1+(\lambda)L$.  But why do we write in this way? What is the significance of $\lambda$ and this form?

For example if we want to find lines through the point of intersection of $3x+4y+5=0$ and $2x+y+4=0$ . The required lines would be obtained by substituting different values of $λ$ in $3x+4y+5+ λ(2x+y+4)=0$

Comment: Can you link to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take up the case of lines first.
Let $L_1(x,y)$ and $L_2(x,y)$ be two lines which intersect at  $(a,b)\\$.
Thus $$L_1(a,b)=0\\L_2(a,b)=0$$Now let $L_3(x,y)$ be another line such that
$$L_3(x,y)=L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)$$Now, if we are able to show that $L_3$ passes through  $(a,b)$,i.e. the intersection point of $L_1$ and $L_2$, our job will be complete.To do this we put  $(a,b)$ in our expression for $L_3$
$$L_3(a,b)=L_1(a,b)+\lambda L_2(a,b)$$
$$\Rightarrow L_3(x,y)=0+\lambda .0$$
$$\Rightarrow L_3(x,y)=0$$So as you can see, for any value of $\lambda$, our line $L_3$ always passes through the intersection of lines $L_1$ and $L_2\\$.
You can the same with any two curves(e.g. two circles) .

Comment: I've seen this before and I've always had a question. Perhaps it is a stupid question - but here you've shown that for any value of lambda you get a line passing through (a,b). My question is - can every line passing through (a,b) be represented in this form? Is such a proof not necessary because somehow it is obvious?