# Why does $Ax+By+C+\lambda(A'x+B'y+C')=0$ represent the set of lines that pass through the intersection of $Ax+By+C=0$ and $A'x+B'y+C'=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

For example, given $\color{green}{l_1:5x-2y-8=0}$ and $\color{blue}{l_2:3x+8y-8=0}$,

[image: img1]

We can compute the set of lines that pass through the intersection of $l_1$ and $l_2$

$$5x-2y-8+\lambda(3x+8y-8)=0$$
$$(5+3\lambda)x+(-2+8\lambda)y+(-8-8\lambda)=0$$ for any $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$

| $$\lambda$$ | $$(5+3\lambda)x+(-2+8\lambda)y+(-8-8\lambda)=0$$ |
| --- | --- |
| $$-1$$ | $$x-5y=0$$ |
| $$1$$ | $$4x+3y-8=0$$ |
| $$2$$ | $$11x+14y-24=0$$ |

[image: img2]

Why does this method work?

---

The closest thread I could find is, [A general circle through the intersection points of line $l$ and circle $S_1$ has the form $S_1+\lambda L$. What is the significance of $\lambda$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743591/a-general-circle-through-the-intersection-points-of-line-l-and-circle-s-1-ha).

> For example if we want to find lines through the point of intersection of 3x+4y+5=0 and 2x+y+4=0 . The required lines would be obtained by substituting different values of λ in 3x+4y+5+λ(2x+y+4)=0

The accepted answer is,

> Let us take up the case of lines first.
> Let $L_1(x,y)$ and $L_2(x,y)$ be two lines which intersect at  $(a,b)\\$.
> Thus $$L_1(a,b)=0\\L_2(a,b)=0$$Now let $L_3(x,y)$ be another line such that
> $$L_3(x,y)=L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)$$Now, if we are able to show that $L_3$ passes through  $(a,b)$,i.e. the intersection point of $L_1$ and $L_2$, our job will be complete.To do this we put  $(a,b)$ in our expression for $L_3$
> $$L_3(a,b)=L_1(a,b)+\lambda L_2(a,b)$$
> $$\Rightarrow L_3(x,y)=0+\lambda .0$$
> $$\Rightarrow L_3(x,y)=0$$So as you can see, for any value of $\lambda$, our line $L_3$ always passes through the intersection of lines $L_1$ and $L_2\\$.
> You can the same with any two curves(e.g. two circles) .

What I understood from this answer is,

- Consider the lines $L_1(x, y)$ and $L_2(x, y)$ which intersept at $(a, b)$ such that $L_1(a, b)=0$ and $L_2(a, b)=0$
- Assume that $L_3(x,y)=L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)$
- Then this means that $L_3$ passes through $(a, b)$

I do not understand how this proves that $L_3(x,y)=L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)$ spans a set of *distinct* lines that pass through $(a, b)$.

In the case of circles of the form $x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ and $x^2+y^2+D'x+E'y+F'=0$ that intersect and are not concentric, we can't have $\lambda=-1$ because we would get their radical axis, not another circle.

I'm looking for a proof by deduction if possible (as opposed to assumption).

Comment: Line $Ax+By+C=0$ contains the common pt, and it has normal vector $n:=(A,B)$; $A′x+B′y+C′=0$ contains the pt, and it has normal $n':=(A′,B′)$. The combined eqn represents a line through the pt, with normal $n'':=n+\lambda n'$. The head of $n''$ lies on the line through $(A,B)$ with *direction* vector $n'$. (Its tail, of course, lies at the origin.) As $\lambda$ varies, $n''$ points in every direction in a $180^\circ$ sweep (*except* directions $\pm(A',B')$ themselves, but we can include them with special accommodation for $\lambda=\pm\infty$), giving every possible line through the common pt.

Answer (score 2):

One explanation is to show that for any point $(p,q)$ outside the line $L_2(x,y)=0$, we can set $\lambda$ so that the the point is on the line $L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)=0$.

This is possible because by the assumption $L_2(p,q)\neq 0$ so we can set $\lambda=-L_1(p,q)/L_2(p,q).$

Edit:
I mean that we can obtain the line $L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)=0$ passing through $(p,q)$ by setting $\lambda=-L_1(p,q)/L_2(p,q).$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand what you mean by "We can set $\lambda$ so that the point is on the line $L_1(x,y)+\lambda L_2(x,y)=0$." Could you add more explanation?

Comment: @Nameless I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that
$$L_1 : \{Ax+By+C=0\} \Longrightarrow \vec{L_1} =(A, B, C)$$
$$L_2 : \{A'x+B'y+C'=0\} \Longrightarrow \vec{L_2} =(A', B', C')$$
The intersection point can be found by solving the system by Cramer rule:
$$\begin{pmatrix}L_1 \\ L_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}A&B&C \\ A'&B'&C'\end{pmatrix}$$

$$x=\frac{CB'-BC'}{AB'-BA'} \qquad y=\frac{AC'-CA'}{AB'-BA'}$$

Doing $R_2 = L_1 + \lambda(L_2) = L_3$
$$\begin{pmatrix}L_1 \\ L_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}A&B&C \\ A+\lambda A'&B+\lambda B'&C+\lambda C'\end{pmatrix}$$

$$x=\frac{C(B+\lambda B')-B(C+\lambda C')}{A(B+\lambda B')-B(A+\lambda A')} 
\qquad y=\frac{A(C+\lambda C')-C(A+\lambda A')}{A(B+\lambda B')-B(A+\lambda A')}$$

$$x=\frac{\lambda CB'-\lambda BC'}{\lambda AB'-\lambda BA'} 
\qquad y=\frac{\lambda AC'-\lambda CA'}{\lambda AB'-\lambda BA'}$$
$$x=\frac{CB'-BC'}{AB'-BA'} 
\qquad y=\frac{AC'-CA'}{AB'-BA'}$$

Which means that $L_1 \cap L_2  = L_1 \cap L_3 $